# zipkin not supported elasticSearch 8.2

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk, zipkin

I'm getting following errors when I connect zipkin 2.23.2  into elasticsearch 8.2.0 but it had worked fine with elasticsearch 7

```
 2022-06-08 10:58:15.281 DEBUG [/] 1 --- [pool-2-thread-1] z.c.k.KafkaCollectorWorker : Kafka polling returned batch of 1 messages.
  2022-06-08 10:58:15.281 DEBUG [/] 1 --- [pool-2-thread-1] z.c.k.KafkaCollector Cannot store spans [62a04135a5f8a5341c7ab0130b77f3ed/1c7ab0130b77f3ed] due to 
 IllegalArgumentException(Elasticsearch versions 5-7.x are supported, was: 8.2)
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Elasticsearch versions 5-7.x are supported, was: 8.2
    at zipkin2.elasticsearch.VersionSpecificTemplates.get(VersionSpecificTemplates.java:227) ~[zipkin-storage-elasticsearch-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at zipkin2.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStorage.versionSpecificTemplates(ElasticsearchStorage.java:355) ~[zipkin-storage-elasticsearch-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at zipkin2.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStorage.doEnsureIndexTemplates(ElasticsearchStorage.java:337) ~[zipkin-storage-elasticsearch-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at zipkin2.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStorage.ensureIndexTemplates(ElasticsearchStorage.java:329) ~[zipkin-storage-elasticsearch-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at zipkin2.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStorage.spanConsumer(ElasticsearchStorage.java:248) ~[zipkin-storage-elasticsearch-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at zipkin2.collector.Collector.store(Collector.java:201) ~[zipkin-collector-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at zipkin2.collector.Collector$StoreSpans.run(Collector.java:230) ~[zipkin-collector-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at zipkin2.collector.Collector.accept(Collector.java:136) ~[zipkin-collector-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at zipkin2.collector.Collector.accept(Collector.java:109) ~[zipkin-collector-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at zipkin2.collector.Collector.acceptSpans(Collector.java:191) ~[zipkin-collector-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at zipkin2.collector.Collector.acceptSpans(Collector.java:172) ~[zipkin-collector-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at zipkin2.collector.kafka.KafkaCollectorWorker.run(KafkaCollectorWorker.java:111) ~[zipkin-collector-kafka-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at zipkin2.collector.kafka.KafkaCollector$LazyKafkaWorkers.lambda$guardFailures$0(KafkaCollector.java:265) ~[zipkin-collector-kafka-2.23.2.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message states

> Elasticsearch versions 5-7.x are supported, was: 8.2

It doesn't seem that Zipkin supports ES 8.x yet and [you're not the only one](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/issues/3453) it seems. So you should probably downgrade your ES cluster for now until Zipkin adds support for ES 8.x.